# Filter rows and select columns based on NA / null percentage

Tags: python, python-polars

I've been checking the other PyPolars questions and didn't find the answer for it.

Is there a more idiomatic way for:

`being df a Polars DataFrame`

- filtering rows based on NA percentage:

```
max_nas_perc = 0.6
df.filter(pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_null() / pl.all().count()) <= max_nas_perc)
```

- filtering / selecting columns based on NA percentage:

```
df.select(
    [
        column for i, column in 
        enumerate(df_nulls.columns) if df_nulls.select(pl.all().is_null().sum() / pl.all().count() <= max_nas_perc).to_numpy()[0][i]
    ]
)
```

Should we add it to the [drop_null() list of examples](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop_nulls.html)? Has it been discussed/discarded as a feature request?

Comment: Is the first example supposed to calculate the percentage for each row? Perhaps the column-based filter could be simplified a bit: `df.select(col.name for col in df.null_count() / df.height if col.item() <= max_nas_perc)`

Comment: To be blunt, the idea of selecting or dropping **columns** based on the underlying data itself has been completely rejected as unworkable. In just a few words, everything breaks if you want column selection to depend on the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks, @jqurious, it does look better!

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, I've figured as much (since I'm not well-versed in Polars/Rust) after seeing the selectors avoiding it. But nulls are a special case, right? In Arrow columnar data, you have validity bitmaps (used, for example, in has_validity()). I'd think there's some usage of this. Also, I'm asking because in other libraries, you have a sort of select_if(expr) interface, but I see it has been avoided or discarded in Polars

Comment: polars uses arrow memory on the backend but the difference, especially with lazyframes, is that at any given select call, it doesn't know what it has until it materializes everything before it.

Comment: The most recent discussion on column-filtering I recall is: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11254 - I'm not entirely sure the row example does what is intended? It seems like you'd need something like `df.select(pl.concat_list(pl.all()).list.eval(pl.element().null_count()).flatten() / df.width)` for a row-based % - perhaps a `.list.null_count()` could be requested.